# Angular 6 TypeError: Cannot read property 'e4b7...f' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, object, interface, key-value

I am having an issue when i tr to initilise an object based on Typescript interface, i am assignining a value but i still get error that the property is underfined.

```js
interface ITableData {
  domainObjectName: string;
  domainObjectType: string;
  recordId: string;
}

interface IDataMap {
  recordId?: string;
  controlId?: string;
}

interface IMap {
  [key: string]: IDataMap;
}

tableData: ITableData[];
dataMap: IMap;

createDataMap() {
    Object.keys(this.tableData).forEach(i => {
      const recordId = this.tableData[i].recordId;
      this.dataMap[recordId] = {
        recordId: recordId,
        controlId: ''
      };
    });
  }
```

Based on the research and debugging I did it seems that typescript is complaining by the fact that I am creating an object key without assigning a value but I am assigning a value.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the site! It appears your code is abbreviated - can we see all of the relevant parts?

Comment: Hi and thanks, I have added the table data with the related interface, is there anything else I forgot to mention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem lies right here, **`this.dataMap[recordId]`**  you are trying to access particular id from an undefined dataMap. You need to have data within it. Either assign to empty array or fill it with Id which holds the id that you want to access.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply, the goals is to populate my empty "dataMap" object, as a key i want the recordId and i am assignig an object of the correct format according to the interface IDatamap. I am not sure i understood what you mean, thanks again

Comment: you need to just set this.dataMap = {};

Comment: It fixed the error, thank you. I thought the dynamic nature of Javascript would allow assigning a property to a declared but not initialized variable but I was wrong.